# Convert Json date to "Date" in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with C#.

I am calling one ActionResult method that returns the list of data from Ajax.

The problem here is I am getting date as `"/Date(1460008501597)/"`.

I don't know how to convert it to display on form using javascript.

Please someone help me it's hard for me to solve.

Comment: Please share your controller code

Comment: Easiest method is to have your ActionResult return it in the final format as a string.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes you are absolutely right but I want to post the whole model so I can't use any extra parameter and I have to set the date in the field of model itself so.

Comment: Yes - you add a read-only property to your model:  `public string DateValue { get { return this.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); } }`  (it wasn't clear from the question if you had a model, so I left it intentionally vague)

Comment: ohh yes that was my mistake a good solution thanks @freedomn-m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a function which return a date if the date string is in the wanted form or the value itself.

```js
function getDateIfDate(d) {
    var m = d.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//);
    return m ? (new Date(+m[1])).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric'}) : d;
}

console.log(getDateIfDate("/Date(1460008501597)/"));
console.log(getDateIfDate('abc'));
```

Comment: @NinaScholz general function could be better thanks. Can you help me a little bit I want to display date like "MM/DD/YY" is it possible in funtion itself or I have to do some operation when I get returned value?

Comment: @NinaScholz Hello can you just pleas check my answer is it right so I can use it!

Comment: you could use `toLocaleDateString` with some options to shape the appearance.

Comment: Ohhh yes amazing but it adds one date ahead means I my date is 3 it return 4!

Answer (score 5):

In pure javascript, you can do this:

```
var date = new Date(Number("/Date(1460008501597)/".replace(/\D/g, '')));
```

Explanation:

```
new Date(
    Number(
        "/Date(1460008501597)/".replace(/\D/g, '') // Removes all non digit characters
    ) // Cast it to numeric
) // Creates a new Date object with the resultant number
```

Now, for more accurate solution for your problem, like display the date w/o javascript(which I think would be better choice), you can improve your question with more detail/information/code.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for thanks @DontVoteMeDown Can you help me little more I want to display date in MM/dd//yy format Can i do it from date variable itself?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I can't use any new js as per requirement for my project can you give me suggestion to do that using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this:(Is it ok)

```
function getDateIfDate(d) {
        var m = d.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//);
        return (new Date(+m[1])).getMonth() + "/" + (new Date(+m[1])).getDate() + "/" + (new Date(+m[1])).getFullYear();
        //return m ? (new Date(+m[1])) : d;
    }
```

Comment: if it works for you, then it's ok. but [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) returns 0-11 and not 1-12.

Comment: I suggested you something really close to this. In the comment(which I deleted) I did like you, but in a simple way. Like, you don't need to create the Date object everytime, why won't you store it in a var? E.g.: `var date = new Date(+d.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//)[1])`.. then `date.getMonth()`..