# how to convert /Date(-664768800000)/ to datetime in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I get item from database like this :

```
{8.12.1948 00:00:00}
```

and when i send it to datatable in view it seems like this:

```
/Date(-664768800000)/
```

how can i handle this ?

```
public ActionResult GetList()
        {
            context entity = new context();
       

            var list = entity.People.Select(x =>
             new
             {
                 EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID,          
                 BirthDate =x.BirthDate,
                
             }).ToList();

            return Json(new { data = list }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


   $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#example').DataTable({
                "bDestroy": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": '/Home/GetList',
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json",
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    "dataSrc": function (json) {

                        return json.data;
                    }

                },
                columns:
                    [
                        { data: "EmployeeID"},
                        { data: "BirthDate" },
       
                    ]
            })
        });
```

Comment: This is really vague.  How are you displaying it?  In a WPF Text Block?  In a console window?  In a debug session?

Comment: @RobertHarvey i showed  how i do that

Comment: @RobertHarvey i want to show datetime like dd-MMM-yyyy  on view can you help me

Comment: It looks like Unix Time (negative numbers represent dates before 01/01/1970). So you could use `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds()`

Comment: So now we're in Javascript.  I have so many questions.  C# doesn't deal in Unix times; do we need a conversion?  How are you getting from C# to an Ajax call, ASP.NET MVC?  (these just scratch the surface).

Comment: yes ASP.NET MVC. Actually @Jimi explained

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing a JSON date into a C# DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130444/parsing-a-json-date-into-a-c-sharp-datetime)

Comment: @hakan I chose the duplicate based on the original version of the question, which did not have any JavaScript. Your question is still only tagged [c#]. I suggest adding [asp.net-mvc] and [javascript] at the least, if not [jquery] and [datatables] as well.

Comment: ok thank you  @HereticMonkey

Comment: Note that `async: false` is deprecated in jQuery. You may also be using a very old version of ASP.NET MVC, as more recent versions send `DateTime` values as ISO 8601 formatted strings.

Comment: The correct duplicate, with those tags, is [Convert Json date to “Date” in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38437506/215552)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var _returnDate = 
DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(long.Parse(Regex.Match(_myUnixDateTime, @"-?\d+").Value)).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"); }
```

This way you get the numeric value by the regex method and then use the .net dateTime conversion FromUnixTimeMilliseconds.